# Wow Cataclysm Vital Leveling Addon's

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have been out of wow for a long time.  I have recently begun to play an arms warrior with 4 friends (mostly dungeons and some pvp). What are the best add-on's to help level a warrior?

Comment: This is sadly a question asking for a list, which does not work will with the question/answer format of this site. You're probably better off asking on some kind of forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over the years Blizzard has been steadily taking the best ideas from the UI customization community and integrating them into the base UI. For example, the game now has a built-in version of QuestHelper which shows (on your map) where to go to kill monsters for quests and turn them in afterward. Frankly, there *are* no "vital" leveling addons anymore.

Some addons can be *useful*, of course, but it depends more on your own play style rather than "here's a list of what you need to play the game".

My advice is to just start playing with no UI addons, and wait until you find an itch that needs scratching before you bother installing any.

Comment: I agree for the most part with this sentiment. If you play with a completely vanilla set of add-ons, you will have no problem leveling. That being said, I think that an add-on that shows you quest levels is pretty helpful, as well as some sort of mini-map coordinates.

Comment: You don't need either of these any more as the quest locations are highlighted on the map and you can turn on "Quest Difficulty" in the "Objectives" section of the Interface menu.

Comment: Excellent advice. With regards to leveling, there are no vital addons. I'd hardly even say that there are vital addons to raiding, but this of course would depend upon the players own opinion. I run with some addons that help me to maximize dps in the instances/raids, but they're hardly vital to my being able to play. Too many players are too dependent on their addons these days.

Comment: I'd argue that raiding is a bit different. It's always been a highly technical activity, so there are a lot of things which addons can really help with. For leveling, though, this just isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree that there are no required "leveling" addons, unless you're talking about leveling *professions*, in which case addons like Gatherer, and Fishing Buddy and similar are useful.

The only addons I ever bother to install are all instance based. Omen, Healbot, DeadlyBossMods, etc.